# Unexpected error during Oracle Service Bus synchronization. Please see the logs for more information.

Tags: osb

**Unexpected error during Oracle Service Bus synchronization. Please see the logs for more information.** 
I have created a OSB cofiguration. I am trying to import OSB projects from the repository. When i drag and drop my osb project in my configuration. Its giving me this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a Known ALSB bug in OSB (Eclipse) workspace. you should not drag-and-drop projects (or) artifcats between projects. Rather use cut-copy-paste for moving artifacts and import-export for creating and moving artifacts between workspaces.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error, and I tried removing, reconfiguring OSB configuration files and OSB projects again and again but failed. At last I found out that if any of your WSDL is in invalid state it will show the above error because it is some conflict with metadata.

Just close the eclipse and go to this path `/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/publish` and delete publish0.dat file and other files also. Start the eclipse.